# Jasmine: Expecting a Form Submission

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have a jasmine test I am writing for a form validation function.

```
function checkTotalWeight(){
   if(//some condition){
    return false;
   }
   else{
      document.Weight.submit();
   }    
}
```

I have successfully written tests for my return false conditions, however, I am having trouble getting my test to

1. See that a submission was made
2. Prevent the submission from actually happening (ie. "message": "Some of your tests did a full page reload!"

I've tried

```
var form = $('form');
var submitCallback = jasmine.createSpy().and.returnValue(false);
form.submit(submitCallback);

var check = checkTotalWeight();

expect(submitCallback).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

which gives me "Expected spy unknown to have been called."

Also, I've tried

```
$('form').on('submit', function () {
   return false;
 });

 var check = checkTotalWeight();

 spyOn(document.Weight, 'submit');       

 expect(document.Weight.submit).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

Which gives me "Expected spy submit to have been called."

I haven't had much luck finding anything online along with the lines of "Expecting a form submission with jasmine".

Unfortunately, I cannot change the source code being tested or I would.

Does anyone have any direction?

Comment: Stupid mistake, I 'half' fixed it by placing spyOn(document.Weight, 'submit'); above the function call.  However, I would like to know if there is a more acceptable way to achieve this.

Comment: `spyOn` is perfectly acceptable if you need to assert that it something has been called. You could also look into stubs, if you wanted to prevent anything from actually happening, you can stub the method, allowing you to control what it does and also assert it has been called